# How can I use devise invitable when my app allows many logins via the same email address?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My website allows people to register multiple accounts with the same email address, separated by domain name. This is done with an additional column domain_id in the user table.

In order to be able to use devise_invitable, I need it to check for existing users by email and domain_id. Currently the initializer will only allow me to specify a single key. Is there any way to override this? The following is what I would like to use in the initializer, but it throws up the error underneath.

```
config.invite_key = :email, :domain_id

undefined method `[:email, :domain_id]=' for #<User:0x0blah0> (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature has now been added to Devise Invitable.

https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/issues/185